# add a link to admin menu bar

Tags: navigation

I want to add the link to tags i.e. /admin/structure/taxonomy/tags directly to admin menu so that it appears next to "Content" link present on admin menu. How to do it?

Comment: the easiest way to do it is with shortcut.. just edit the shortcut links

Comment: @Jayendra Kainthola How to set permission on same item ,that only administrator can see this menu item?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve using below step:

- Go to Administration -> Structure -> Menus
- Click on 'Add links' in 'Management' menu row
- Add 'Menu link title' and 'Path' for menu item.
- Set 'Parent link' for the menu item, so it would display in correct position.
- Save the form

Update:

By default, `Management menu` be only dispaly to `administrator` or the user which has permission to view it.

If you want to set any specific visibility permission, you can use [Menu item visibility](https://drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility) module.

> This module exposes configurable and extendable visibility settings
>   for menu links. For example, if you want to create a 'My account' link
>   that points to /user, both anonymous and registered users have access
>   to the /user path, so both will see the link, even if anonymous users
>   do not technically have an account. Using this module will allow you
>   to only have your 'My account' link visible to registered users, and
>   hide it from anonymous users.

Answer (score 4):

In drupal 8 here is how you would attach a menu-link to the toolbar. Add a file my_module.links.menu.yml to your module:

```
my_module.admin_settings_form:
  title: 'MyModule Settings'
  route_name: my_module.admin_settings_form
  description: 'Custom settings'
  parent: system.admin
  weight: 15
```

Source: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/add-menu-item-drupal-toolbar

Comment: how do you add a link to the shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would like to add to this, make sure to go in Taxonomy page and drag the item all the way to the bottom, the hierarchy can be confusing, and it won't show even if you choose --administration as parent item